# Is there a way to add a css style class to a Java String inline

Tags: java, css, javafx

Is there a way to add a css class to a Java String inline?

To add a class to a Label:

```
String siteNameText = "This is : ";
String siteName = "StackOverflow.com";
Label siteNameLabel = new Label(siteNameText + siteName);
siteNameLabel.getStyleClass().add("site_name_bold");
```

Is there a way to add the style class only to `"StackOverflow.com"` in `siteName`? The only other option would be separating them by placing them into two different Labels.

Comment: There's no way to do this using just JavaFX controls; you need to use two separate `Label`s (or two `Text`s in a [`TextFlow`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/text/TextFlow.html). You might also want to look into a third-party control, such as [RichTextFX](https://github.com/TomasMikula/RichTextFX).

Answer (score -1):

Check AttributedString class, it does exactly what you ask.

Edit: However, you can't directly use it in a Label/JLabel, you will need to draw the string yourself using a graphics object.

Comment: To answer the question, you need to show how to use an `AttributedString` in conjunction with a JavaFX `Label`, or other JavaFX control, and CSS styling.